# A ``continuous'' family of measurable subsets of [0,1], each with a positive measure, admits a ``continuous'' subfamily with non-empty intersection?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Let $\{Y_x\}$ be a family of measurable subsets of [0,1] indexed by $x \in [0,1]$, and such that each set $Y_x$ has a positive (Lebesgue) measure. Is there always a subset $X \subseteq [0,1]$ with **positive measure** and such that $\bigcap\limits_{x \in X} Y_x$ is nonempty?

Intuitively it seems to be true, possibly under some mild extra assumptions (say compactness of $Y_x$'s).

Comment: Assuming e.g. the continuum hypothesis, there is a family $\{Y_x\subset[0,1]:x\in[0,1]\}$ of compact sets of positive measure such that for any **uncountable** set $X$ the intersection $\bigcap_{x\in X}Y_x$ is empty.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give a construction please?

Comment: That is, reduction to the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: If $[0,1]=\{x_\alpha:\alpha\in\omega_1\}$ then for each $\alpha$ the set $\{x_\beta:\beta\gt\alpha\}$ has positive measure (its complement is countable) so it contains a compact $Y_\alpha$ of positive measure. Any intersection of uncountably many $Y_\alpha$'s will be empty.

Comment: How the map $\alpha \mapsto x_{\alpha}$ is defined?

Comment: The continuum hypothesis says that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ or in other words that there is a bijection between $\mathbb R$ (or $[0,1]$) and $\omega_1$. Of course I can't define such a bijection.

Comment: I don't understand this stuff very well myself. That's why I'm commenting instead of posting an answer. Let an expert on set theory post a real answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't chat, and I don't know much more than I've already told you. (Hope I got that much right.) Wait a while and an expert will come along and give you a good answer.

Comment: Sure. I'm no specialist so I'm taking time to understand the solution. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @bof  Your comments are right and your solution is simple and elegant. I suggest you post it as an answer.

Comment: Related: [Can all uncountable (but small) families of sets with positive measure have an uncountable subfamily with an intersection of positive measure?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/385017/15780)

Answer (score 1):

The comments contain essentially a full answer, and CH is not needed, though perhaps there is a more elementary counterexample.

Let $c$ be the cardinality of the reals.

*Lemma:* Every subset of $[0, 1]$ of positive measure has cardinality $c$.

This is well-known. Here is one proof. Let $X \subset [0, 1]$ be a set with $\mu(X) > 0$. Then the convolution $f(x) = 1_X * 1_{-X}$ is continuous and $f(0) = \mu(X) > 0$, so there is some neighbourhood of zero on which $f > 0$. This implies that $X - X$ contains an interval, so $|X| = |X - X| = c$.

Now by choosing an bijection between $[0, 1]$ and $c$, there is an ordering $\prec$ on $[0,1]$ for which every $x$ has $< c$ predecessors. This implies that $\{y \in [0, 1] : y \prec x\}$ has measure zero by the lemma, so $\{y \in [0, 1] : y \succ x\}$ has full measure. Let $Y_x$ be a compact subset of $\{y \in [0, 1] : y \succ x\}$ of positive measure. Now the intersection of any collection of $c$-many $Y_x$'s is empty.

EDIT: Alessandro Codenotti points out that $\{y \in [0, 1] : y \prec x\}$ can be nonmeasurable if CH does not hold. The lemma only shows the inner measure is zero. So I'm not adding anything to bof's solution after all.

EDIT 2: Here is a different solution. By inner regularity (and the lemma) it suffices to define $Y_x$ ($x \in [0, 1]$) such that $\bigcap_{x \in C} Y_x = \emptyset$ for every compact set $C$ of cardinality $c$. Note that there are only $c$ such sets (because there are only $c$ open sets). Let $\{C_\alpha : \alpha < c\}$ be all such sets. For each $\alpha < c$ in turn do the following. Choose $x_\alpha, y_\alpha \in C_\alpha \setminus \{x_\beta, y_\beta : \beta < \alpha\}$ and define $Y_{x_\alpha} = [0, 1/3]$ and $Y_{y_\alpha} = [2/3, 1]$. Define also $Y_x = [0, 1]$ for all $x \in [0, 1] \setminus \{x_\alpha, y_\alpha : \alpha < c\}$.

A reasonable hypothesis to add would be something about the measurability of the map $x \mapsto Y_x$, maybe the graph $\Gamma = \{(x, y) : y \in Y_x \}$ should be measurable. In this case I think the claim follows from Fubini's theorem:
$$\int \mu(\{x : y \in Y_x\}) \, dy = \mu(\Gamma) = \int \mu(Y_x) \, dx > 0,$$
so there is some $y \in [0, 1]$ such that
$$\mu(\{x : y \in Y_x\}) > 0.$$

Comment: One of the problems with the question is that $[0, 1]$ is being used just as an indexing set with no additional structure, so talking about the measure of a set of indices is a kind of type error.

Comment: Indexing is just a notation for function, where the index set is the domain. It is perfectly correct to talk about measure of subsets of the domain of a function.

Comment: Since you are not using ordinals, the statement "there is an ordering $\prec$ on $[0,1]$ for which every $x$ has $<c$ predecessors" requires proof.

Comment: It's not clear to me why $\{y\in [0,1]\colon y\prec x\}$ is measurable, your Lemma applies to measurable sets, but it is surely consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}+\neg\mathsf{CH}$ to have a set $X\subseteq \Bbb R$ with $|X|<\mathfrak c$ and $X$ nonmeasurable, this happens for example if you force to add $\aleph_1$ random reals over a model of $\mathsf{GCH}$.

Comment: You are right, I overlooked that, I guess this construction does require CH then.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I added a different argument.

Comment: Regarding your first edit: The hypothisis that every set of cardinality less than $\mathfrak c$ is Lebesgue measurable (i.e. has measure zero) is weaker than the continuum hypothesis, so your first argument does add something to what I said in my comment.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I understood the first solution, but not the second solution by @SeanEberhard In fact, the trick based on Fubini's theorem is what I needed in the context of my question (I won't give it here since it doesn't add any ideas to the question itself), and measurability of $\Gamma$ indeed suffices to make it work.